# How to rename title column in Document Library using code?

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, rename

Everybody loves renaming columns. The title column is a favorite of mine and I can't seem to rename it via code:

```
SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList("MyList");
Guid guid = new Guid("fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247"); //Title column
SPField field = list.Fields[guid];
field.Title = "Testing";
field.Update();
list.Update();
```

The **title** column always stays the title column (the `DisplayName` at least). Of course I don't want to rename the `InternalName` or anything crazy, but since you can't remove the column it would be nice if it actually had a meaningful name in my SP context.

So the question in short: **How to rename the title column/field in a document library using code (that means C# - not XML)?"**

PS: Of course it works via the UI. Go to document library settings > Columns > Title and you can change the name to your liking (this is updated on all views then)

---

Further investigation shows that it doesn't even work with the `SchemaXML`:

```
string schema = field.SchemaXML;
schema.Replace("Title", "NewNameHere");
field.SchemaXml = schema;
field.Update();
list.Update();
```

Still the field's display name is "Title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Localization is the issue. I need to change the `TitleResource` additional to the `Title`:

```
field.TitleResource.SetValueForUICulture(new CultureInfo(1033), "My title");
```

As [explained here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/24163/how-to-rename-title-column-in-document-library-using-code).

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for poping up old QA - if I set list.Title = "ABC" and update, the property will be successfully set, but title will not change. Event debugging list for second time I see my newly set title "ABC" value..